# IntelliJ IDEA not working on Ubuntu 17

Tags: java, ide, intellij

I installed IntelliJ and it got installed successfully then when I tried to configure project structure, it wasn't working. I was clicking that option but nothing was happening.

Also when I tried to create a new project, i was getting the same result. I was simply clicking that option but nothing was happening.

I re-installed it several times but nothing happened and the result was same.

Comment: Yes, I installed the community package into the /opt/ folder by executing the idea.sh file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intellij-idea-community snap package works OK with openjdk-8-jdk without requiring a lot of special configuration, and it also is updated automatically. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk  
sudo snap install --classic intellij-idea-community
```

This installs the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition version 2018.1.1.

Comment: Oh yes..!! I am new here so I don't have enough knowledge about this site. Again thanks a lot for this..!!